# How can I run some cut commands in centos container?

Tags: docker, centos

I use docker running a CentOS8 container.

I know the image is minimized, so I can not use some commands in it.
such as: `clear`, `systemctl`.

```
[root@e07da148cc16 /]# clear
bash: clear: command not found
```

is there any way to install some module, so I can run it? or whether there is other not minimized CentOS image with all commands ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker run -it amazonlinux bash`

Come with basic commands and ready for you to customize (yum install) further.

Comment: How about `service` or `systemctl`, I check there do not have this type commands.

Comment: You don't run (while technically possible) `systemd` (required pid 1) in docker. You run single program in your container, there's no need of systemd to coordinate/manage daemon services inside the container.